# Closing ServerSocket - how to properly check if client socket is closed?

Tags: java, sockets

I create a new thread that runs the following code:

```
public static void startServer() throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(55000);
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
}
```

The above code is run in a thread. Now, in my main class, I successfully create a socket
connection to the server and I have checked it's integrity which is fine. here is the code:

```
Socket testServerSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 55000);
assertEquals("/127.0.0.1", testServerSocket.getInetAddress().toString());
assertEquals(55000, testServerSocket.getPort());
```

This runs perfect. Then, again from my main, I kill the server connection that closes the connection on the server side. However the following code keeps failing:
assertEquals(false, testServerSocket.isBound());

It keeps returning true. Likewise, if I check the remote IP address for the connection, it doesn't return null, but rather '/127.0.0.1'. Any ideas why this might be happening? Many thanks for your help

Comment: How do "kill the server connection"? Call serverSocket.close()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on sockets (I know what they are, but haven't ever used sockets on Java, only with C on Linux), but like [JavaDoc for java.net.Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) states, *'A socket is an endpoint for communication between two machines'*. So while closing server-side socket does destroy the connection between the two sockets (server- and client-side), your client-side socket is still bound, hence the `isBound()` is returning true. Maybe you meant to call `isConnected()` or `isClosed()`?

Comment: Hi there. What I ended up doing was attempting to reestablish a connection with the server. If an exception was returned containing "Connection refused" then I deduced that the server socket was closed.Thanks for the help!